# Rails 3.2: how to find all parents from a collection of children

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, parent-child

Given a collection of "Books", what is the best way to find all "Authors" (no duplicate) ?

So let's say we have a classic association:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

The way I do it right now is this:

```
@books = Book.where("some condition")
@authors = Author.where(:id => @books.map(&:author_id))
```

Is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way :

```
@books = Book.where("some condition").includes(:author)
@authors = @books.map(&:author).compact.uniq
```

Explanation :

- include will eager load authors so you don't get dreaded O(n) db calls each time a book wants its author...
- uniq to remove the duplicate authors (you might want to use inverse_of option in that case not sure)

Comment: Not sure this is better. Doing a map on :author_id won't call the db. Doing an "includes" will trigger a 2nd call to the db, so it seems to me both our solutions need 2 calls. Also, you need to add ".uniq" after or before compact, which isn't required in my solution.

Comment: I am sorry but doing map(&:author) is like doing books.each {|book| book.author} and if author isn't there it'll fetch it on the db. If you have 30 books that's 30 calls. And yes I mixed up uniq with compact (compact is for removing nils). I am not saying this solution is better, your's is fine. It's just an alternative. The 2 db calls BTW is one of activerecord strategies to fill up the result (instead of a big join)

Comment: oups sorry thought you said map(&:author) won't trigger the db... diagonal reading is playing trick on me!

Comment: hehe, you did it again, guess you meant map(&:author_id) in that last comment, you really want me to do map(&:author) don't you ^^.

Comment: no no got it right this time :) map(:author_id) will not trigger db indeed, it's in the column.

Comment: right! :) I see you removed the compact, but it seems you might need both compact & uniq in case a book doesn't have any author.

Answer (score 0):

```
@books.each.collect(&:author)
```

or just simply:

```
@books.collect(&:author)
```

You can read more about collect [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect)

Comment: You'll call the db each time you get an author when you do that, and you can have duplicates (I will clarify my question on that matter)